# I need help on this lerping issue. I am trying to make a platformer game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(Once it reaches point B, it goes to point A and back to point B in a smooth and orderly fashion). For some reason, the platform refuses to move and stays put. I have tried many things such as using `vector3.movetowards` and much more but nothing makes it move.

Here is the code. (Point A and Point B are empty game objects that are not parented to the platform)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTwoTransforms : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform pointA;
    public Transform pointB;
    bool HeadingtowardsB;
    bool HeadingtowardsA;
    public float speed = 10;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = pointA.position;
        HeadingtowardsB = true;
        HeadingtowardsA = false;
        GlideAround();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GlideAround()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while ((Mathf.Abs((pointB.position.x - transform.position.x) + (pointB.position.y - transform.position.y)) > 0.05f) && HeadingtowardsB == true && HeadingtowardsA==false )
            {
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, pointB.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

                if(Mathf.Abs((pointB.position.x - transform.position.x) + (pointB.position.y - transform.position.y)) > 0.05f)
                {

                    HeadingtowardsB = false;
                    HeadingtowardsA = true;
                }

            }
            HeadingtowardsB = false;
            HeadingtowardsA = true;


            while (Mathf.Abs((pointA.position.x - transform.position.x) + (pointA.position.y - transform.position.y)) > 0.05f && HeadingtowardsA==true && HeadingtowardsB==false)
            {
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                transform.position=transform.position=Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pointA.position, speed*Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are no error messages, the platform won't move. The platform is still colliding and it seems to behave like a normal platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTwoTransforms : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform pointA;
    public Transform pointB;
    bool HeadingtowardsB;
    bool HeadingtowardsA;
    public float speed = 10;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = pointA.position;
        HeadingtowardsB = true;
        HeadingtowardsA = false;
        StartCoroutine(GlideAround());

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GlideAround()
    {
        //Because we want a specific speed, the % between the two points 
        //that we should be at will be equal to (time * speed) / distance
        //with an adjustment for going backwards. 
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(pointA, pointB) * 2;
        float lapTime = distance / speed;
        float startTime = Time.time; 
        Debug.Log("The platform speed is: "  + speed.ToString());
        Debug.Log("The distance for one full lap is: "  + distance.ToString());
        Debug.Log("One lap will take: "  + lapTime.ToString() + " seconds");


        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            float elapsedTime = (Time.time - startTime) % lapTime;
            float progress = elapsedTime / (lapTime / 2);
            if (progress > 1){
                progress = 2 - progress;
            }
            Debug.Log("The platform speed is currently: "  + progress.ToString() + "% between pointA and pointB");
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(pointA.position, pointB.position, progress);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you Lerp uses a percentage between two points as the return value. You need to give it a percent, not a speed.

Here is an implementation that uses speed, like you wanted, but @derHugo's answer with PingPong is much simpler!

Comment: I finally fixed it. The solution was really simple. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @ninety-ninehundred No problem. Don't forget to upvote answers that helped you understand and to accept an answer if it's the one you used!

Comment: Okay. I am new to stack overflow. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

`GlideAround()` is an `IEnumerator` and can not be called like a method. You have to start it using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

```
StartCoroutine(GlideAround());
```

---

Also note that `speed * Time.deltaTime` makes little sense for usage in [`Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html). You usually would want a constant value between 0-1 in your case (since you re-use the current position as first parameter).

E.g. a value of 0.5 means: Every frame set the new position to the center between the current and the target position.

Since you catch it using a threashold of `0.05f` this should be fine but in general I wouldn't use `Lerp` like this ... with very small values you might never really reach the target position.

---

I would therefore prefer to either control the **constant speed** and use

```
bool isHeadingA = true;

while(true)
{
    // if it was intended you can ofourse also again use
    // Vector2.Distance(transform.position, isHeadingA  ? pointA.position : pointB.position) <= 0.05f)
    while (transform.position != (isHeadingA  ? pointA.position : pointB.position))
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, isHeadingA  ? pointA.position : pointB.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // flip the direction
    isHeadingA = !isHeadingA;
}
```

`!=` has a precision of `0.00001` and is fine here since `MoveTowards` avoids overshooting so at some point it will surely reach the position if `speed != 0`.

---

Or alternatively you **can** use Lerp if you rather want to control the **duration** of the movement with a **smoothed in and out speed** using e.g. [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) as factor and [`Mathf.SmoothStep`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html) for easing in and out like

```
while(true)
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    // linear pingpong between 0 and 1
    var factor = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1);

    // add easing at the ends
    factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);
    // optionally add even more easing ;)
    //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(pointA.position, pointB.position, factor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are not using coroutines properly, as pointed out in [derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004140/1253136).

---

However, I'll provide my own answer, seeing that you are making the rookie mistake of *way* over-engineering this problem.

I think teaching by example might be the most appropriate in this case, so here it is:

If the points dictating the platform's movement are static, you should do this with animation. I won't explain it here. Tutorials [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO19dA2jksk) can easily be found all over the unity tutorials, unity forums, other StackOverflow Q&As, and youtube.

---

If your points are dynamic, this is more than enough:

```
public class MoveTwoTransforms : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform pointA;
    public Transform pointB;
    public float speed = 10;

    void Start() {
        transform.position = pointA.position;
        StartCoroutine(GlideAround());
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveTowards(Vector3 targetPosition) {
        while (transform.position != targetPosition) {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator GlideAround() {
        while(true) {
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveTowards(pointA));
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveTowards(pointB));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Just a final note:
If the platform should have physics or a collider, it is preferable to add a `Rigidbody`, set it to be `kinematic`, and to the movement by setting the `Rigidbody.position` instead of the transform. This is because that is updated on the physics loop (`FixedUpdate`) rather than the frame loop (`Update`), and avoids some bugs related to asyncrony between the physics system and moving objects through transform's position.

```
rigidbody.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(rigidbody.position, //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked.

public IEnumerator GlideAround()
    {

```
    while (true)
    {
        while (HasReachedA == false)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();



            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, pointA.position, 0.01f);
            if ((Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(pointA.position, transform.position)) < 0.01f))
            {
                HasReacedB = false;
                HasReachedA = true;
            }
        }

        while (HasReacedB == false)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, pointB.position, 0.01f);


            if ((Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(pointB.position, transform.position)) < 0.01f))
            {
                HasReacedB = true;
                HasReachedA = false;
            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want it to go really fast at first, then move slowly?

Comment: This code will move 43% of the distance in the first second, 25% (68%) in the second second, 13% (81%) in the third second and will flip after about 7 seconds, no matter what the distance is

Comment: In other words, the speed is not *constant*

Comment: (The above numbers are assuming 60 FPS. 90FPS makes things much faster, 30FPS will be slower)

Comment: Yes that is the effect I wanted.